# doMC: Only together with foreach?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, feature-selection, domc

I want to run an R script to use the [reversed feature elimination](http://caret.r-forge.r-project.org/featureselection.html) from the caret package on a computer cluster. Ideally I would like to run it on multiple cores in parallel. In the script of a coworker, I found the use of the `doMC` package. I read that this package is used together with the `foreach` package. But in the script I got, there is simply the library imported and in the line before the `rfe` command there is a `registerDoMC(5)`. There is not a single use of `foreach` in the whole script.

Will the `doMC` do anything here or does it only work together with `foreach`?

Is there a way to distribute the resource consuming `rfe` process on multiple cores?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the documentation:

> rfe can be used with "explicit parallelism", where different resamples
>   (e.g. cross-validation group) can be split up and run on multiple
>   machines or processors. By default, rfe will use a single processor on
>   the host machine. As of version 4.99 of this package, the framework
>   used for parallel processing uses the foreach package. To run the
>   resamples in parallel, the code for rfe does not change; prior to the
>   call to rfe, a parallel backend is registered with foreach (see the
>   examples below).

So, `caret::rfe` uses `foreach` internally.

Comment: Ok thank you. Did only read about the doMC and forgot to look closely at rfe again...stupid me